# How to fix a possibly corrupted json file? Problems with a curly bracket character "{" (Python3)

Tags: json, python-3.x, curly-braces

This is such a weird problem I don't even know how to ask, but I'll try. I have some json files that have web scrape data in them, multiple entries per file and they look like this:

```
{
"doc_id": "some_number",
"url": "www.seedurl1.com",
"scrape_date": "2019-10-22 16:17:22",
"publish_date": "unknown",
"author": "unknown",
"urls_out": [
"https://www.something.com",
"https://www.sometingelse.com/smth"
],
"text": "lots of text here"
}
﻿{
"doc_id": "some_other_number",
"url": "www.seedurl2.com/smth",
"scrape_date": "2019-10-22 17:44:40",
"publish_date": "unknown",
"author": "unknown",
"urls_out": [
"www.anotherurl.com/smth",
"http://urlx.com/smth.htm"
],
"text": "lots more text over here."
}
```

I was trying to format them, so that each entry would be on their own line, like this:

```
{"doc_id": blah blah....} 
{"doc_id": blah blah blah...}
```

So I did this:

```
    # Read the file
    f = codecs.open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='replace')
    text = f.read()
    f.close()

    # Check if }{ was found; 
    # this prints nothing for original files but finds everything in a hand written file
    pattern = '}{'
    print('Before editing: ', (re.findall(pattern, text)))

    # Getting rid of excess newlines and whitespaces
    newtext = " ".join(text.split())

    # Check if } { was found;
    # this prints nothing for original files but finds everything in a hand written file
    pattern = '} {'
    print('After editing: ', (re.findall(pattern, newtext)))

    # Put newlines in the right places
    finaltext = re.sub('} {', '}\n{', newtext)

    # Write the new JSON
    newfile = file[:-5]+'_ED.json'
    nf = codecs.open(newfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
    nf.write(finaltext)
    nf.close()
```

The thing is, the code works perfectly on a hand written test file with the same structure, but not with the original files, or the smaller test files derived from the originals.

I tried to do a simple search for "}" and "{" separately in a text editor, which turns out ok. But if I try to search for "}{" or "} {", nothing is found. Though I can see that they clearly are there.

One last find: I tried to open the edited version of my small test file in Nano in Linux and moved over the problem area. For some reason it takes two presses of the right arrow key to move over the "{" curly bracket. So there is clearly something weird there. How do I find out what? Or any other suggestions that might help?

Comment: Instead of giving the { or } can you try copy pasting the pattern directly from the data? Sometimes there are some non-utf-8 characters hidden in plain sight.

Comment: Why are you not using python's `json` library? It's much more convenient for operations and debugging like this.

Comment: @Saharsh Because the file isn't valid JSON?

Comment: Does this help? https://pypi.org/project/json-lines/

Comment: @cricket_007 my bad. Wasn't aware initial file can have OP's defined syntax.

Comment: @Saharsh I did try to make a dictionary out of the json file with the library at first, but it didn't work.

Comment: @morko it will only work if file is a valid JSON and from your post it seems there is a possibility that it's not (because of your custom formatting)

Comment: ".. but not with the original files .." Not *how*? What happens instead? "It didn't work" may be an accurate description but it does not help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would just make a JSON array to begin with...

Otherwise, I would suggest not replacing anything, and simply count the matching brackets.

```
count = 0
objects = 0
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for i, c in enumerate(f.read()):
      if c == '\n':
        continue
      elif c == '{':
        if i > 0 and count == 0:
          print()  # start new line before printing bracket
        count += 1
      elif c == '}':
        count -= 1
        if count == 0:  # found a complete JSON object
          objects += 1

      print(c, end='')
    print(f'\n\nfound {objects} objects')  # for debugging
```

For the given text, I ended up with this

```
{"doc_id": "some_number","url": "www.seedurl1.com","scrape_date": "2019-10-22 16:17:22","publish_date": "unknown","author": "unknown","urls_out": ["https://www.something.com","https://www.sometingelse.com/smth"],"text": "lots of text here"}
{"doc_id": "some_other_number","url": "www.seedurl2.com/smth","scrape_date": "2019-10-22 17:44:40","publish_date": "unknown","author": "unknown","urls_out": ["www.anotherurl.com/smth","http://urlx.com/smth.htm"],"text": "lots more text over here."}

found 2 objects
```

Comment: This actually worked even with the problematic files! Thank you very much!

Comment: I picked this one as the accepted answer because it worked before I found out what the problem with my files was. After I found out my problem, @Saharsh 's answer worked also and was simpler (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import json

with open(filename) as infile:
    data = json.loads("[" + infile.read().replace("}\n{", "},\n{") + "]")
    for i in data:
        print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
{'doc_id': 'some_number', 'url': 'www.seedurl1.com',.....
{'doc_id': 'some_other_number', 'url': 'www.seedurl2.com/smth',.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which is kinda close to what you were attempting

```
import json

with open('test.txt') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
file = ['{'+i+'}'for i in "".join("".join(file).split("\n"))[1:-1].split("}{")]

for i in file:
    print(json.loads(i))
```

`json` is being used here to validate individual JSON only. This gives

```
{'doc_id': 'some_number', 'url': 'www.seedurl1.com', 'scrape_date': '2019-10-22 16:17:22', 'publish_date': 'unknown', 'author': 'unknown', 'urls_out': ['https://www.something.com', 'https://www.sometingelse.com/smth'], 'text': 'lots of text here'}
{'doc_id': 'some_number', 'url': 'www.seedurl1.com', 'scrape_date': '2019-10-22 16:17:22', 'publish_date': 'unknown', 'author': 'unknown', 'urls_out': ['https://www.something.com', 'https://www.sometingelse.com/smth'], 'text': 'lots of text here'}
```

Comment: Oops. Need to handle space i think and we should be okay. Let me work on this. Thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Updated the answer. Completely forgot to add `\n` in `split()` which was removing all white spaces.

Comment: I tried this one and it proved very useful. At first it did not split at ```"}{"``` but after I printed out the result it showed me that there was a ```\ufeff``` hidden between the curly braces, so ```split("}\ufeff{")``` solved the problem. Thank you!